# Jenkins BitBucket integration broke suddenly

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket

I have an onpremise Jenkins server setup with Blue Ocean. This is connecting to a BitBbucket cloud account. I haven't done any builds in a couple of months and when I went to Jenkins today it couldn't build any builds and the Scan Mutltibranch pipeline was failing as well.

Error is:
com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.bitbucket.api.BitbucketRequestException: HTTP request error. Status: 403: Forbidden.

`{"type": "error", "error": {"message": "To make a call, you need to use an app password."}}`

I've tried using an app password and my BitBucket user password and neither are working. When I try to create a new pipeline with either of these passwords I just get an "Invalid username and/or password" error.

I'm not sure if anything has changed with Jenkins (or a plugin) or with BitBucket.

Comment: Have you enabled 2FA on your account?

Comment: Yes. I have 2FA enabled, but that hasn't been something I've changed recently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling 2 Factor Authentication has fixed the problem. I'm not sure why this was ok before and not now.